# IOException was unhandled "The process cannot access the file

Tags: vb.net, ssis

I am trying to reading the file, reformat some rows, then overwrite the file line by line.

I know the problem is cause by opening the existing file twice, but I don't know how to fix it.

```
Public Sub Main()

    Dim objStreamReader As StreamReader
    Dim objWriter As StreamWriter

    If Dts.Variables("File").Value.ToString.Length > 0 Then


        'read the file
        objStreamReader = New StreamReader(Dts.Variables("File").Value.ToString)

        'write the file
        objWriter = New StreamWriter(Dts.Variables("File").Value.ToString)


        'read file line by line
        Dim row, line As String
        Dim isFirstRow As Boolean = True
        Dim numColumns As Integer = 0
        row = ""
        Do While objStreamReader.Peek() <> -1
            line = objStreamReader.ReadLine() 'read a line
            If line.Trim() = "" Then
                Continue Do 'skip blank line
            End If

            If isFirstRow Then 'first line in the file (it's always a complete row)
                numColumns = CountNumColumns(line) 'record the number of columns
                isFirstRow = False
                objWriter.WriteLine(line)
            ElseIf CountNumColumns(line) = numColumns Then
                'the line is a complete row
                objWriter.WriteLine(line)
            Else
                row = row & line
                If CountNumColumns(row) = numColumns Then
                    'we have a complete row
                    objWriter.WriteLine(row)
                    row = ""
                End If
            End If
        Loop

        'close files
        objStreamReader.Close()
        objWriter.Close()

    End If

    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub

'Counts the number of columns in a given line
Function CountNumColumns(ByVal line As String) As Integer
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    For index As Integer = 0 To line.Length - 1
        If line(index) = "|" Then
            count = count + 1
        End If
    Next
    Return count
End Function
```

Comment: Text files are not random access.  Read the entire file in using `File.ReadAllLines` close the stream, then process the array.  Rather than writing line by line, you can write all lines back out.

Comment: You cannot read and write from/to the same file at the same time. Just create a temporary file to write to (and after finishing rename it); it would be enough by defining the `StreamWriter` with the new path. Also you should rely on `Using` to make sure that the (`StreamReader` & `StreamWriter`) objects are properly disposed. Here you have an example showing how to do this with `StreamReader`: http://www.dotnetperls.com/streamreader-vbnet

Comment: Unless the file is quite large in which you don't want to read the entirety in one fell swoop

Comment: I usually agree with Plutonix, but not this time. `StreamReader` can be used in any context. `ReadAllLines`/arrays are limited by memory and thus can only be used up to certain size. I don't think that you should change this part of your code, as far as there is nothing bad with always using `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` (properly).